# How can we have a contained GridBagLayout, with preferredSize, with vertical scroll only?

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know how to add a ScrollBar to a JPanel with a Gridbaglayout, allowing the Gridbaglayout to still reposition components on the horizontal axis. I've tried adding the scroll bar - but when I do the Gridbaglayout repositioning of components on the horizontal stops working and the components go off the side of the screen when I reduce the window width. How can we include vertical scroll, while allowing the Gridbaglayout to still reposition components on the horizontal axis. And help would be appreciated.

The GridBagLayout should still move the components.

The code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(addCustomer());


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 480));
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Component addCustomer(){
        JTextField textField1;
        /***********************Initialize Fields******************************/

        JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[2];

        labels[0] = new JLabel("Left side - more components to add here");
        labels[1] = new JLabel("Right side - more components to add here");

        textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JComboBox<String> materialTitlesCombo = new JComboBox<String>();

        materialTitlesCombo.addItem("-");
        materialTitlesCombo.addItem("test");
        materialTitlesCombo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 500));
        materialTitlesCombo.setMinimumSize(materialTitlesCombo.getPreferredSize());
        /****************************Create the canvas**************************/
        GridBagConstraints constraints;

        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();


        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 0.5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(-20,20,0,0);
        panel.add(labels[0], constraints); //Left side

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 0.5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(-10,-9,0,9);
        panel.add(textField1, constraints); // TextField 1

        constraints.gridx = 8;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 0.5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(-15,15,0,0);
        panel.add(labels[1], constraints);//Right side

        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should not take > 500 LOC To express that you can't add a scrollpane to a tabbed pane!  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: "I can add the scroll bar by itself, but it stops the grid layout from being responsive upon resize!" - Thnks for the advice on code length!. The problem is that the panels components need to be contained horizontally, and include a vertical scroll. When the user resizes the screen manually, the components need to react horizontally, with a vertical scroll visible.

Answer (score 1):

To add a scrollable `JPanel` as a tab, you can do the following:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(addCustomer());
pane.addTab("...", scrollPane);
```

I noticed that you never add the `JTabbedPane` component to the `CustomerPane`, which means the tabbed pane will never be rendered in the UI.  You can try the following:

```
private void initializeUI() {
    ...
    add(pane);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main problem is that the panel needs a         preferredSize;  frame.setPreferredSize(UI_Settings.getMinimumScreenSize()); Which is smaller than the display, so the customerPane starts small, than the user can maximize the screen. The contents need to be displayed fully, horizontally, maximized and with preferredSize without using the horizontal scroll. But when the scrollbars are added, the gridbaglayout does not stay contained.. It needs a vertical scrollbar, but horizontally it just needs to be contained within the panel when resized. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add setMaximumSize, and setPreferredSize with a minimumSizeValue to the parent panel, containing a nested panel that uses gridbaglayout housing your components.

panel.setMaximumSize(getYourMinimumSize);
panel.setPreferredSize(getYourMinimumSize);

Works with nested tabPanes and nested Panels.